# C++ manipulation using iomanip library

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, setw

I am new to C++ STL libraries and need help.
I want to add two numbers suppose A = 4555 and B = 50, and output them as:

4555
  +50
4605

Another Examples:

500000 + 12

500000
        +12
500012

If i am storing both A and B in integer data type while the sign '+' in character data type. How can i manipulate them to get the preferred output.
I just cant figure out how to manipulate two variables together.

Comment: Combine the sign and the number into a string: `std::string s = signChar + std::to_string(value);` Now print `s` with formatting to taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use constant width *(or variable width equal to the maximum width of the numbers involved)* with `std::setw` from `<iomanip>` as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

void display_sum(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << a  << "\n"
              << std::setw(10) << ("+" + std::to_string(b)) << "\n"
              << std::setw(10) << (a+b) <<"\n" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    display_sum(4555, 50);
    display_sum(500000, 12);
    display_sum(503930, 3922);
}
```

Output:

```
  4555
   +50
  4605

500000
   +12
500012

503930
 +3922
507852
```

[Online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fe5305d3b452340)

Comment: Hi Nawaz, I would make some slight changes to your soln, including determining the number of digits at run-time to ensure the field is large enough, as well as using the `showpos` flag to print a + or - symbol based on sign of `b`. Here's my slightly more complete example: http://ideone.com/ApLZEV

Answer (score 2):

You might utilize the manipulators std::showpos, std::noshowpos and std::setw:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int a = 4555;
    int b = 50;
    std::cout
        << std::noshowpos << std::setw(10) << a << '\n'
        << std::showpos   << std::setw(10) << b << '\n'
        << std::noshowpos << std::setw(10) << (a+b) << '\n';
}
```

If you want a width depending on the values you may use three std::ostringstream(s) and create intermediate strings (without setw). After that you print the strings using the maximal length of each for setw:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    int a = 4555;
    int b = 50;

    std::ostringstream as;
    std::ostringstream bs;
    std::ostringstream rs;
    as << std::noshowpos << a;
    bs << std::showpos   << b;
    rs << std::noshowpos << (a+b);
    unsigned width = std::max({ as.str().size(), bs.str().size(), rs.str().size() });
    std::cout
        << std::setw(width) << as.str() << '\n'
        << std::setw(width) << bs.str() << '\n'
        << std::setw(width) << rs.str() << '\n';
}
```

See also:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/

Note: You may have a look at the manipulator std::internal.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the fields can fit a maximum number of 7 characters. Perhaps you want to resize the strings to 7 before writing. e.g. `fname.resize(7)`.

To format it as you want you need to `#include <iomanip>` and use `std::left` and `std::setw(7)`.

```
file1 << left << setw(7) << fname
      << tab << setw(7) << lname
      << tab << setw(7) << street
      << tab << setw(7) << city
      << tab << setw(7) << state
      << tab << setw(7) << zip << endl;
```